# Unable to get the pages which have their calcualted date.time field equal today using CAML

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, caml-query, caml, camlviewfields

I am working on an online SharePoint site collection, where I have a calculated column named "ExpiryDate" of type Datetime, and I want to get all the pages which have their expiry date equal today, i tried the following CAML query , but it did not return any pages:

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name ='ExpiryDate'/><Value Type='DateTime'>Today/></Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>3000</RowLimit></View>";
```

Any idea why my query is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see there is a syntax error in your code near `<Today/>`. Use it like below:

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name ='ExpiryDate'/><Value Type='DateTime'><Today/></Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>3000</RowLimit></View>";
```

If that does not work then try using:

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ExpiryDate" /><Value Type="Calculated"><Today/></Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```